# Can a Docker container (and its Python script) be a RESTful API?

Tags: python, rest, docker

I have a python script that will take a single argument. The script makes calls to 3rd party APIs, which obviously need to be server-side because of the API keys.

I want to make a website that makes an ajax call (or similar) to run the python script and give it some browser-side data.

I thought this would be a good project to use Docker for, but I can't find anything to indicate that this will work.

Is python not the right tool? Is Docker not the right tool?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit (also in comments)

> I've deployed a test image/service/cluster successfully on DigitalOcean, but I don't see how I can configure the endpoint to be RESTful

Edit (for source code)

To test the setup, I've been using a Docker-provided tutorial.

Dockerfile

```
#use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.6.2-slim
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
ENV NAME World
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: username/repo:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - webnet 
networks:
  webnet:
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis, RedisError
import os
import socket

# Connect to Redis
redis = Redis(host="redis", db=0, socket_connect_timeout=2,         
socket_timeout=2)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    try:
        visits = redis.incr("counter")
    except RedisError:
        visits = "<i>cannot connect to Redis, counter disabled</i>"

    html = "<h3>Hello {name}!</h3>" \
           "<b>Hostname:</b> {hostname}<br/>" \
           "<b>Visits:</b> {visits}"
    return html.format(name=os.getenv("NAME", "world"), hostname=socket.gethostname(), visits=visits)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

It suddenly seems like I probably just need to change `@app.route("/")`...

Comment: If you deploy it somewhere and make it publicly accessible, sure

Comment: I've deployed a test image/service/cluster successfully on DigitalOcean, but I don't see how I can configure the endpoint to be RESTful

Comment: You have to use docker config files to make the right ports connect to your app, and your app has to have a server listening for incoming connections on that port

Comment: Are you referring to this part of docker-compose.yml `ports: - "80:80"`?

Comment: Probably. I don't remember

Comment: Take a look at [help/on-topic].

Comment: @pvg You could be more specific

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes, its possible.

I recommend you **first** run your Python code outside of a container and try to connect to the droplet before putting in Docker, just to make sure it works.

Once you have the basic connection working, you can move into a container, and build out the REST API. (or GraphQL, if you're into that)

Containers aren't RESTful, the app they host *can be*. You don't have any REST endpoints yet, looks like, though.

Anyways, you've mapped the port

```
ports:
   - "80:80"
```

And the app in running there

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Assuming you have opened your firewall to allow port 80 on DigitalOcean, that's all you need

Just fire up your http://digital-ocean.address

> Is python not the right tool?

Use whatever you're comfortable with. For example, if you just want make HTTP requests,  straight shell commands to do cURL commands and echo HTML responses would work.

> Is Docker not the right tool?

It's not required. Even if you have keys, placing them within a container just adds a layer of redirection, not obfuscation

Comment: Appreciate the input -- this is totally uncharted territory for me! My code does have my actual info for `username/repo:tag`. Using `@app.route("/name")` works. (Of course, many other things have to change then.)

Comment: Well, then you'd need to use `/name` in the droplet url